# Encoding issue when using read.csv in r

Tags: r

Im very new to R but I have the following problem I cannot find a solution to-

```
players <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vaastav/Fantasy-Premier-League/master/data/2017-18/player_idlist.csv",encoding = "UTF-8")
name <- ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vaastav/Fantasy-Premier-League/master/data/2017-18/players/")
urls <- paste0(name,players$first_name,"_",players$second_name,"/gw.csv")
urls <- c(urls) #Redundant line
```

Which correctly returns the URL values in a vector with the appropriate UTF-8 encoding. I then try to combine the data in the URLs with:

```
result <- lapply(urls, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
result <- do.call(rbind, result)
```

I get:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vaastav/Fantasy-Premier-League/master/data/2017-18/players/HÃ©ctor_BellerÃ­n/gw.csv': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
```

The issue is that the player names that are correctly encoded in urls is now reverting back to the gibberish characters, which seems to cause the error. The example being: "HÃ©ctor_BellerÃ­n" being converted from "Héctor_Bellerín".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the following command?
`urls <- c(urls)`

Comment: Sorry - its redundant code I left in when trying some previous fixes.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to encode the urls (special characters and spaces will otherwise not work properly)

```
library(urltools)
encoded_urls <- url_encode(urls)
result <- lapply(encoded_urls, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You can read [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urltools/vignettes/urltools.html) for more info

Comment: Perfect! thanks. In case anyone reads this in the future, one player has a broken name that needs cleansing with:
    players <- gsub("De Gea","de Gea",players)
    players <- data.frame(players1)